# mysqli and singleton

Tags: php, singleton, mysqli

```
<?
class DbConn {
    const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    const DB_USER = 'root';
    const DB_PASS = 'pw';
    const DB_NAME = 'db';

    static private $instance = NULL;
    private $_db;

    static function getInstance()
    {
      if (self::$instance == NULL)
      {
        self::$instance = new DbConn();
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            throw new Exception("Database connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
        }
      }
      return self::$instance;
    }

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->_db = new mysqli(self::DB_HOST, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASS, self::DB_NAME) or die('Couldnt connect');
    }

    private function __clone() {}

}

DbConn::getInstance()->query();

?>
```

Im just learning and know I've got to singleton pattern, I tried to make my own DBConnect class using singleton, but when I'm trying executing it, it gives an error when calling DbConn::getInstance()->query(); saying that Call to undefined method DbConn::query() What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wich error? it points to a line on PHP or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following after the `__construct` function

```
public function query($sql)
{
    return $this->_db->query($sql);
}
```

then try

```
DbConn::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM Table"); //Replace your sql
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `query()` on a object of class `DbConn` - which hasn't got any `query()` method.

The implementation of the singleton pattern is good in your example. But you can't call the `mysqli` functions on the `DbConn` object directly, you have to *wrap* them or provide a getter for the private `_db` property, and call `query()` on *that* object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to

- extend the mysqli class to use methods from that class
- or write a query method yourself.
- or make the $db public and use `DbConn::getInstance()->$db->query();`

Why make it a Singleton? mysqli does **connection pooling**, and making it a singleton add extra complexity without any benefits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new at this, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Can't you simply extend the mysqli class and change the contructor a little?

```
class DbConn {
```

becomes

```
class DbConn extends mysqli {
```

and:

```
$this->_db = new mysqli(
    self::DB_HOST, 
    self::DB_USER, 
    self::DB_PASS, 
    self::DB_NAME) or die('Couldnt connect');
```

becomes

```
parent::__construct(
    self::DB_HOST, 
    self::DB_USER, 
    self::DB_PASS, 
    self::DB_NAME) or die('Couldnt connect');
```

Now, `DbConn::getInstance()->query();` should work